# reset step counter value every day android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, counter

I made this android app which counts footsteps and that works well, but it can only reset the steps when the device has rebooted. I would like it to store the counted footsteps in the SharedPreferences prefs. Then reset it to zero every day, but i am not sure how to proceed. By running the reset() function it only sets the visual steps to zero.how to calculate how the calorie intake is calculated

Answer (score 0):

In `onSensorChanged()` you need to сheck if the current date is equal to the one stored in the prefs (for simplicity, you can store the string "01/01/2022").

- If not equal, then save the current date and the number of steps from sensor;
- If equal, then you need to subtract the steps stored in prefs from the current value from the sensor - this is exactly the value of steps per day at the moment.